# How to remove a specific pattern of junk values from a file using awk or sed?

Tags: awk, gsub

I have two types of pattern in my xml file which I want to remove without disturbing any other meaningful patterns.

```
testname="@TEST-Loop${c}- 05030502956 @TEST - verify that the  Handler returns an error indicating â~@~\call barredâ~@~]." enabled="true">
```

I want to change it to

```
testname="@TEST-Loop${c}- 05030502956 @TEST - verify that the  Handler returns an error indicating call barred." enabled="true">
```

I tried below code but it didnt worked

```
awk '{if(match($0,/@TEST.*" enabled="true">$/))
 gsub(/â~@~\\/,"");
 gsub(/â~@~\]/,"");
  print}' $file >> tmp.jmx && mv tmp.jmx $file
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to represent the character `à`.  A hex dump of the bytes you want to replace should help (but then you can probably figure it out from there yourself).

Comment: I tried with ascii value 131 of â but it didn't worked, any specific way of writing it?

Comment: That would be `\203` octal but do you really think that's what it is?  I would find it rather unlikely -- did you really check with a hex dump or similar?  More likely it's 0xE2 (octal `\342`)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you are attempting to replace looks like a mangled UTF-8 character viewed in some legacy 8-bit encoding.  Because you don't specify which encoding that is, we have to do a fair amount of guesswork.

You are asking about Unix tools, so this answer assumes that you are using some U*x derivative or have access to similar tools on your local box (Cygwin?)

To find the actual bytes in the string you want to replace, you can do something like

```
bash$ grep -o '...~@~...' -m1 "$file" |
> od -Ax -tx1o1
0000000    67  20  e2  7e  40  7e  5c  63  61  0a                        
          147 040 342 176 100 176 134 143 141 012                        
000000a
```

I use `od` for [portability reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17319/can-hd-and-od-replace-each-other); you might prefer `hexdump` or `xxd` or some other tool.  The output includes both hex and octal, as [octal is preferred in Awk](http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote) but hex is ubiquitous in programming otherwise.  I keep a couple of characters of context around the match in case `â` would in fact be stored in a multibyte encoding in your sample, but here, in this somewhat speculative example, it turns out it is represented by the single byte 0xE2 (octal `342`).  (This would [identify your terminal encoding](https://cdn.rawgit.com/tripleee/8bit/master/encodings.html#e2) as Latin-1 or some close relative; maybe one of the CP125x Windows encodings.)

Armed with this information, we can proceed with

```
awk '{ gsub(/\342~@~./, "") }1' "$file"
```

to replace the pesky character sequence, or perhaps

```
sed $'s/\xe2~@~.//' "$file"
```

which assumes your shell is Bash or some near-compatible which allows you to use C-style strings `$'...'` -- alternatively, if you know your `sed` dialect supports a particular notation for unprintable characters, you can use that, but that's even less portable.

(If your `sed` supports the `-i` option, or your Awk supports `--inline`, you can replace the file in-place, i.e. have the script replace the file with a modified version without the need for redirection or temporary files.  Again, this has portability issues.)

I want to emphasize that **we cannot guess your encoding** so your question should ideally include this information.  See further the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag wiki](/tags/character-encoding/info) for guidance on what to include in a question like this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried bash$ grep -o '...~@~...' -m1 "$file" |
> od -Ax -tx1o1 but it didnt worked for me. any other command I can use. I have never used this hexdump or xxd .

Comment: "Did not work" how...?  The `>` is a prompt, not part of the command.

Comment: I get this > od -Ax -tx1o1
000000

Comment: Then the `grep` pattern is wrong, and the actual characters in the file do not match that regular expression.  I can only guess what bytes are actually there, based on what you posted -- if the excerpt you posted isn't actually representative, my guess will be wrong. Try something like `grep -m1 '@TEST-Loop${c}- 05030502956 @TEST '`to feed the entire first matching line to `od`.  In the worst case, run `od` on the whole file, or use a pager with hex dump facilities.

Comment: Oh, and if you get warnings about the input encoding from `grep`, try prefixing the `grep` command with `LC_ALL=C` -- so the entire command would be something like `LC_ALL=C grep -m 1 '05030502956' "$file" | od -Ax -t1x1o`

Comment: I got some value after using your last command what I need to check there, the output is too big I cannot paste here: 0000a0  72  2e  63  6f  6e  74  72  6f  6c  2e  41  4c  4d  54  72  61
       162 056 143 157 156 164 162 157 154 056 101 114 115 124 162 141

Comment: 000140  72  65  64  e2  80  9d  20  61  6e  64  20  20  69  73  73  75
       162 145 144 342 200 235 040 141 156 144 040 040 151 163 163 165

Comment: You can't meaningfully post that in comments.  Please [edit] your question to include the information.  However, the snippet you posted simply decodes to `r.control.ALMTra`...`red” and  issu` and so does not expose the bytes we need to see.

Comment: I used \342 alone in gsub and now â is removed from my file but when I use gsub(/\342~@~\\/,"") all together it is not working. Any Idea ?

Comment: I continue to repeat the same instruction. The text representation in your question apparently does not properly reveal what actual bytes are in the file. Once you figure that out, it will be trivial to diagnose why your current regex is failing, and what to use instead. A hex dump is a good way to find that out, but if you are unfamiliar with the very basics of character encoding, I don't think this is the right site for your question.

Comment: If the actual input is UTF-8 curly double quotes, the precise bytes will be `\342\200\234` for [opening double quote](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) and `\342\200\235` for [closing double quote](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm).